# Question on foundry

Tags: solidity, foundry

I am using foundry, I am new in it, I am noticing one thing that whenever I delete or install any package I am having to add commit, is it nature of foundry?

Comment: `forge install --no-commit`

Comment: Same for uninstall?

Comment: There's no commit when running `forge remove`

Comment: Foundry uses git submodules to track dependencies so if you install or update an existing library dependency it'll point to that newly installed dependency and it modifies the file that tracks all submodules which should be committed.